# ¿Cómo obtener la clase de un valor guardado como Object en Java?

Tags: java

Estoy escribiendo un programa en el cual me estoy viendo obligado a utilizar cosas como esta:

```
HashMap<String,Object> valores = new HashMap<>();
valores.put("valor1", "abc");              // Se guarda como objeto String
valores.put("valor2", (int) 123);          // Se guarda como objeto Integer
valores.put("valor3", (double) 3.1416);    // Se guarda como objeto Double
```

Ahora bien, en otra parte del código necesito guardar estos valores en una base de datos. Estoy utilizando una sentencia preparada, y me gustaría hacer algo como esto:

```
ps = conn.preparedStatement("insert into tbl (v1, v2, v3) values (?,?,?)")
for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    if(/*valores.get(String.format("valor%d",i)) es String*/)
        ps.setString(i, (String) valores.get(String.format("valor%d",i)));
    else if(/*valores.get(String.format("valor%d",i)) es Integer*/)
        ps.setInt(i, (Integer) valores.get(String.format("valor%d",i)));
    else if(/*valores.get(String.format("valor%d",i)) es Double*/)
        ps.setDouble(i, (Double) valores.get(String.format("valor%d",i)));

}
```

Así pues, mi pregunta específica es: ¿Cómo puedo, en tiempo de ejecución, obtener el tipo de una variable guardada como `Object`?

Comment: > me estoy viendo obligado a utilizar cosas como esta
Solo puedo imaginarme que te están apuntando con una pistola.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu amigo se llama `instanceof`, *(sacado de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935858/is-there-any-equivalent-syntax-for-c-sharp-type-gettype-in-java) y [aquí](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm)).*

Teniendo una variable de tipo `Object` puedes obtener el tipo de dato interno almacenado en esta de la siguiente forma:

```
Object O = "Hello world";
if (O instanceof String) System.out.println("Es un string");
```

Resultado:

```
Es un string.
```

Lo que aplicado a tu código actual quedaria así:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) 
{
    if(valores.get(String.format("valor%d",i)) instanceof String)
        ps.setString(i, (String) valores.get(String.format("valor%d",i)));
    else if(valores.get(String.format("valor%d",i)) instanceof Integer)
        ps.setInt(i, (Integer) valores.get(String.format("valor%d",i)));
    else if(valores.get(String.format("valor%d",i)) instanceof Double)
        ps.setDouble(i, (Double) valores.get(String.format("valor%d",i)));

}
```

Comment: Convendría agregar un último `else throw new RuntimeException(...)` o algo por el estilo. Así si alguien  agrega datos de otro tipo el error salta.

Comment: Pues si, pero eso ya es decisión del op.

Answer (score 3):

> me estoy viendo obligado a utilizar cosas como esta

Solo puedo imaginarme que te están apuntando con una pistola :-)

La verdad que es horrible (incluyendo lo de "valor1", "valor2"...)

Pero, si realmente estás obligado a hacer eso, entonces no es necesario que averigües el tipo real en runtime (la respuesta en este sentido de NaCL es correcta), puedes usar directamente [setObject()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int,%20java.lang.Object)), Java tiene un [mapeo default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html#1034737) de sus tipos a los tipos de SQL que en tu caso (y suponiendo que no uses más tipos que esos) debería alcanzar.

```
ps.setObject(i, valores.get(String.format("valor%d",i)));
```

PS: De paso, respecto a `instanceof`: en realidad `instanceof` no sirve para obtener el tipo/clase de un objeto, sino para verificar que el objeto es de un cierto tipo. Y "ser de un cierto tipo" quiere decir que la clase real es esa o un descendiente. Por ejemplo, en tu caso `instanceof Number` devolverá verdadero cuando el valor sea Integer o [Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html), (ambos extienden [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), y por lo tanto "son un Number", a pesar de que su clase verdadera sea otra).
Si quieres obtener la clase concreta debes usar [`object.getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()).

Comment: jajaja... pues lo de la pistola no te creas que está tan alejado de la realidad ;) En cuanto a lo de "valor1", "valor2"... son solo ejemplos. Probaré con `setObject()`

Answer (score 0):

No se si te valdrá , pero si por tipo te refieres a la clase de la variable puedes hacer simplemente :

```
variable.getClass();
```

Esto te devolverá un objecto de tipo Class.